# stdint.h not found in Alpine docker image

Tags: docker, alpine-linux

I am getting a `error: no include path in which to search for stdint.h` error message when building a docker image from alpine:edge, that leads to other errors like `unknown type name 'uint32_t'` and failure when compiling a program.

As far as I understand, `stdint.h` is part of the C++ standard library and should be present, unless there is something broken within `alpine:edge`, which I don't think will be the case.

My docker image is the following:

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN apk update && apk add \
        git \
        make \
        gcc \
        python3 \
        ldc \
        && git clone --recursive https://github.com/lomereiter/sambamba.git \
        && cd sambamba \
        && make \
        && mv sambamba /usr/local/bin/ \
        && cd ../.. \
        && rm -r sambamba

WORKDIR /wd
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/sambamba"]
```

Note that the image `alpine:edge` is necessary, because the `ldc` package is only available on it. How to fix this? Why isn't `stdint.h` found?

Comment: Wild guess: do you need to install the g++ package to get the C++ compiler and standard library?

Comment: Nice guess, it does actually solve the problem with `stdint` (compilation still fails but that is a different error now). I am surprised that this is not provided by `gcc`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To successfully compile Sambamba, you need some additional packages:

- g++ (for the C++ compiler and includes)
- zlib
- zlib-dev (for the zlib Header files)

Overall, this modified Dockerfile should do the trick:

```
FROM alpine:edge

RUN apk update && apk add \
        git \
        make \
        gcc \
        g++ \
        zlib \
        zlib-dev \
        python3 \
        ldc \
        && git clone --recursive https://github.com/lomereiter/sambamba.git \
        && cd sambamba \
        && make \
        && mv sambamba /usr/local/bin/ \
        && cd ../.. \
        && rm -r sambamba

WORKDIR /wd
ENTRYPOINT ["/usr/local/bin/sambamba"]
```